# How to use function prototype in objects?

Tags: perl, oop

With Perl 5+, does this code map my internal array?

```
package somepackage; 
(...)
sub someMappingFunction (\&@) {
    my $this = shift; 
    #well should not because the object is supposed 
    #to a blessed hash reference and not a function.
    my $f = shift; 
    map { &$f($_) } $this->{'some_internal_array'}; 
}
```

How can I correct it in order to call the function this way?

```
sub create_mapping_function {
    # this is even more complicated in my real application!
    my $value = shift; 
    my $key = shift;
    return sub {
           my $line = shift; 
           $line=~s/$key/$value/;
           return $line; 
    }
}
(... long, very long ...)
myObject->someMappingFunction create_mapping_function('$option',42);
(...)
mySecondObject->someMappingFunction create_mapping_function('$option',65);
```

Comment: I think the more pertinent question here is whether you need function prototypes altogether.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=861966

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use prototypes, unless you know *exactly* what they do. The purpose of prototypes is changing how the call site is *parsed*, and to *impose context* on the arguments. There are various circumstances where prototypes are ignored, and method calls are one of these cases (because it is impossible to tell which method will be called at runtime).

The prototype `(\&@)` means that the function should be called like

```
foo &bar, 1, 2, 3;
```

I have never seen that before in my whole Perl life. Instead of actually invoking `bar`, that function is passed as reference. Don't do that. Also, it doesn't work without the `&` sigil, and it doesn't work with methods anyway.

Prototypes are also not type constraints.

Your `someMappingFunction` should look like:

```
sub someMappingFunction {
  my ($self, $function) = @_;
  return map { $function->($_) } @{ $self->{some_internal_array} };
}
```

- This sub doesn't expect further argument after the coderef.
- Hashes only ever contain scalars, e.g. references, but never arrays themselves. We have to dereference that array reference with circumfix `@{ ... }` to flatten it. The `map` operates on lists, not on arrays.

Your `create_mapping_function` is OK as it is.

The invocation would look like

```
$someObject->someMappingFunction(create_mapping_function("value", "key"));
```

Points to note:

- Objects are just special scalar variables, therefore they have a `$` sigil.
- I am not sure that you really want to pass the literal string `'$option'`. Note that it won't be evaluated in the substitution.
- Methods call either take no args, then we can leave off the parens, like `$foo->bar`. Otherwise, the method invocation is immediately followed by an arglist in parens, e.g. `$foo->bar()` or `$foo->bar(1,2,3)`.

Comment: Don't say "Do not use prototypes.". Prototypes have its uses, especially when writing non-OO code, where it can help to find errors at _compile time_ (i.e. if prototyped function calls are written without parentheses). Of course, prototypes are useless in OO code.

Comment: @SlavenRezic You do have a point. I qualified my statement to “Do not use prototypes unless you know exactly what they do”. Once in a while I use prototypes myself, most often for syntactic sugar in functional code. I do not buy the “it helps finding errors” argument: Prototypes can generally neither assert type nor exact number of arguments, and when they can, it is uneccessarily restrictive (The world would be a better place if List::MoreUtils::zip would take arrayrefs instead of array variables. Instead, that prototype looks like `\@\@;\@\@...`).

Comment: When used together with parenthesis-less function calls, then prototypes help at least in two points: mistyped function names, and too few or too many arguments. Better than nothing, it helped me often enough. And I really hate errors which happen only at runtime...

Comment: @Slaven Rezic, They also cause errors (e.g. `foo(@args)`) since their purpose is to change parsing rules rather than provide validation. Also, they are unreliable as they are silently ignored if code isn't placed in the right order (e.g. `sub bar { foo() } sub foo($) { } bar();`). I will admit they are useful to provide interesting syntaxes (e.g. `try { } ...` and `mypush(@a, LIST)`).

Comment: As I wrote before: parenthesis-less function calls. So this should be `sub bar { foo } sub foo($) { } bar;`, and here the error is trapped (yes, I forward-declare my subs if necessary).